# Is there any XBMC remote control for Ubuntu?

Tags: xbmc

I have a Raspberry Pi running Raspbmc (XBMC) connected to the home network. Is there any XBMC remote control application I can use on my Ubuntu notebook to control the Raspbmc (XBMC)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a web interface for XBMC which allows you to use your browser to pick media, but it is more limited than the UPnP remote controls for eg, Android. Nonetheless, if you just want to play things it's perfectly servicable.

Enable the web interface from within XBMC with `System->Settings->Network->Services->Allow Control of XBMC via HTTP`.

Then point a browser at `http://host:8080/`, where `host` is the IP address of the device running XBMC. If (as implied by `raspbmc`) the device is a raspberry pi, by default I think you should be able to use `raspberrypi.local` instead of needing to look up the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I use an app on my iPhone called [xbmcRemote](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/official-xbmc-remote/id520480364?mt=8). Or are you looking for an [IR remote](http://www.raspbmc.com/wiki/user/configuring-remotes/)?